# Fix "sudo: /usr/bin/sudo must be owned by uid 0 and have the setuid bit set"

Tags: sudo, root

on an r-pi 4b running raspbian buster...

I accidentally set the owner of /usr/bin to pi ...

Now I don't have sudo (as per title).  I also don't have a root password for su.  nor can I start in runlevel 1 since it's systemd...

Is there *anything* I can do, other than wipe the system and reinstall?  I was going to anyway, but there's some painfully acquired and unbacked-up command lines on there...

I'm tempted to suggest the raspbian developers have made it a little *too* difficult to get root privileges...

Cheers.

Comment: Reinstall.  Treat this as a learning experience.  Hopefully in future you will be more careful.

Comment: I agree with Joan. If you desperate to "fix" it mount on a Linux computer. You could change cmdline.txt to boot to a root shell. The BEST option would be to restore from your backup.

Comment: See above for the fix, but why the scare quotes around "fix"?  Am I forgetting something?

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:

Simple really!  With the SD card in my desktop, I did:

```
/media/me/root/usr$ sudo chown root:root bin
/media/me/root/usr/bin$ sudo chown root:root bin/sudo
/media/me/root/usr/bin$ sudo chmod u+s bin/sudo

/media/me/root/usr$ ll bin/sudo
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 147560 Jan 21  2021 bin/sudo*
```

Although I'm reasonably familiar with *nix, it didn't immediately occur to me that I could override access privileges simply by mounting the file system in a different machine with a compatible OS, and editing the file permissions directly.

Comment: Your question states "I accidentally set the owner of `/usr/bin` to `pi`", and according to this answer you also needed to fix the `sudo` binary. If you recursively changed the owner of everything in `/usr/bin` you might get other problems later. In this case a reinstall would be highly recommended. Apparently you did not (correctly) copy&paste the commands as the 2nd & 3rd prompts do not match the commands.

Comment: Thanks Bodo.  Happy to report nothing else was changed.  I was messing about trying to install torch on buster, and I hacked the build script, so it wasn't just doing chmod -R that did the damage.  Anyway, I found a micro SD in the drawer and now using 64bit bullseye.  Tbh, I was only using buster out of bloody minded determination not to upgrade  :D

Comment: When I first posted, I thought it was only the directory, since that's the only change I made manually.  I'm not sure what changed the sudo binary, and not sure I want to...

Comment: For reference, with the sdcard mounted elsewhere, i fixed this with `sudo chmod u+s usr/bin/{at,beep,chfn,chsh,gpasswd,newgrp,passwd,pkexec,sudo}` based on a Xenial's output of `ls -l /usr/bin | grep rws`, although `at` and `beep` are not present.